# Can you define a varaible that you then use as the list of elements to \foreach loop over?

Tags: lists, foreach

I have a piece of code where I'm iterating over a list of items, but I do this in several places and would like to avoid having to redefine that list every time. This is what I have working:

```
\foreach \f in {193, 87, 88, 85, 80, 81, 79, 89}{                                      
     \includegraphics{\f.png}  
}
```

I'd like instead be able to something like this:

```
\foreach \f in \allfs{                                      
     \includegraphics{\f.png}
}
```

Is there a way to define `\allfs` such that I can iterate over it? I tried just doing a `\newcommand\allfs{{193, 87, 88, 85, 80, 81, 79, 89}}` but that doesn't work. It instead looks for the file `{193, 87, 88, 85, 80, 81, 79, 89}.png`

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I was having trouble figure out the right way to phrase things to search

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\foreach` I would rather use the `/.list` key, which avoids the need for a macro like `\f` as loop variable and avoids groups. In this context, it is particularly convenient because it can be paired with the `/.expanded` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\allfs{{a,b,c,duck}}
\pgfkeys{include graphics/.code={\includegraphics{example-image-#1.pdf}\par}}% \par is only added for this example
\pgfkeys{include graphics/.list/.expanded=\allfs}
\end{document}
```